# How to properly set 'data_class' for form collection in Symfony2?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I would like to have a collection of forms. My brick form is defined like:

```
class ImportPaymentsType extends AbstractType
{
    public function getName()
    {
        return 'import_payments_type';
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('caisse', 'entity', array(
            'label' => null,
            'class' => 'ACME\AppBundle\Entity\Caisse',
            'property' => 'name',
            'empty_value' => 'Choose an option',
        ))
        ->add('label', 'text', array(
            'label' => null,
        ))
        ->add('credit', 'number', array(
            'label' => null,
        ));
    }
}
```

In controller I construct this form like:

```
    $data = array(
        'imports' =>
            array(
                'caisse' => $em->getRepository('ACMEAppBundle:Caisse')->findOneByCode('P6015C'),
                'label' => null,
                'credit' => null,
            )
    );

    $importForm = $this->createFormBuilder($data)
        ->add('imports', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new ImportPaymentsType(),
        ))->getForm();
```

The error I get is:

> The form's view data is expected to be of type scalar, array or an
>   instance of \ArrayAccess, but is an instance of class
>   ACME\AppBundle\Entity\Caisse. You can avoid this error by
>   setting the "data_class" option to
>   "ACME\AppBundleBundle\Entity\Caisse" or by adding a view
>   transformer that transforms an instance of class
>   ACME\AppBundleBundle\Entity\Caisse to scalar, array or an instance
>   of \ArrayAccess.

I tried to change ImportPaymentsType but it didn't work:

```
    ->add('caisse', 'entity', array(
        'label' => null,
        'class' => 'ACME\AppBundle\Entity\Caisse',
        'property' => 'description',
        'empty_value' => 'Choose an option',

        'data_class' => 'ACME\AppBundle\Entity\Caisse'

    ))
```

What should I do? Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`'imports'` should be an array of array.

Try with:

```
$data = array(
    'imports' =>
        array(
            array(
                'caisse' => $em->getRepository('ACMEAppBundle:Caisse')->findOneByCode('P6015C'),
                'label' => null,
                'credit' => null,
            )
        )
);
```